# fcl-json jsonConf: save json formatted?

Tags: lazarus, fpc

I save file via jsonConf (TJsonConfig) and json file is of 1 long long line. (many keys are in it). How to save it formatted? Nicely like at web.

Lazarus 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `FormatJSON` of the protected member FJSON with the right parameters. To get access to FJSON you have several choices (class helper, cast as a dummy sub class or create a real sub class).

Because the TJsonConfig destructor calls `flush()`, it's quite possible that the file will be overriden at the end with the default format. So the best option would be to sub class TJsonConfig and to override the destructor without calling inherited:

```
destructor TMyJSONConfig.Destroy;
var
  data: string;
  str: TMemoryStream;
begin
  if Assigned(FJSON) then
  begin
    data := FJSON.FormatJSON(); // here you can change default parameters
    with TMemoryStream.Create do try
      Write(data[1], Length(data));
      SaveToFile(FFilename);
    finally
      free;
    end;
    FreeAndNil(FJSON); 
  end;
  // skip flush() in inherited, avoid to save again the file.
  TComponent(Self).Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Tks. Bad design of `TJsonConfig`. Need to ask FPC team. To add an option to save formatted. It's easy...

Comment: Or either ask them to put `Flush()` as virtual...But since you seem to use Lazarus, don't forget that it's still distributed with FPC 2.6.4...

Comment: `Flush` virtual: bad since `AssignFile`, etc in it

Comment: You wouldn't be forced to call `inherited` in the overriden method but instead you could rewrite it completly.